# Typo3 9.0 Carousel all links redirect to current page

Tags: typo3

I have a typo3 9.0 page with a carousel on top of my page.

The carousel itself does not link anywhere, however all its items do. The problem is, in the generated site all links redirect to the current page and not to the in the backend assigned target.

Assigning a link to the carousel itself doesn't change anything, it still redirects to the current page only.

Whether my carousel items are headers or text with images doesn't change the behaviour at all.

Comment: Do you mind to update to 9.1? There are plenty of breaking changes in 9.0 which can affect bugs. Either be on the latest change (maybe master) or go to the stable one in 8.7

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple times.
This can come from missing variables in the [f:link.page](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Page.html) viewhelper.

E. g. 
If the variable {foo.linkUid} is empty or has wrong content (text or an array) the link in the FE will always point to the same site.

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{foo.linkUid}">My carousel slide</f:link.page>
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.